# referencing MySQL with Connector/NET and Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, connector-net

I am rebuilding a `Visual Studio 2008` project in `Visual Studio 2013 Express`.  I installed the latest community version of `MySQL for Windows (5.6.14)` and even after adding the reference to the newest `MySql.Data` assembly (`6.7.4 version 4.0`) the following error appears.

```
> Warning   1   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
> assembly "MySql.Data, Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
> make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
> by your code, you may get compilation errors. OVS1
```

It's strange that the error message refers to version 6.2.3.0.  I then uninstalled `Connector/NET` which was part of the `MySQL for Windows` installation and then installed the "stand-alone" version of `Connector/NET 6.7.4`.  The same error message appears.  Adding the reference via browsing to the assembly for `Connector/NET 6.7.4 version 4.0` also does not seem to install the reference and the same error appears.  How do I fix this?

Suspecting it might be that the newest Express IDE is the problem, I did the following.

I uninstalled `VS 2013 Express`, uninstalled the standalone `Connector/NET`, uninstalled `MySQL for Windows` and then installed `Visual C# Express 2010` and reinstalled `MySQL for Windows 5.6.14`.  The same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within Visual Studio or Visual C#, remove the reference to `MySql.Data` and then add it again.

Answer (score 0):

No available dot net mysql connecter hs been released yet,lets just wait for the mysql developers to finish it